# How to get the text associated with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to access the text associated with a checkbox. What is the attribute of the chekcbox object that points to the text associated with that. Thus, in the following example, I would like to alert the user saying "Selected -- TextXYZ".

```
<form id="idForm" class="classForm">
<input type="checkbox" id="idCheckbox"> TextXYZ <br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clickCheckbox() {alert("Selected -- " + this.name);}
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#idCheckbox").click(clickCheckbox);
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: getting next node (also text nodes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207916/jquery-getting-next-node-also-text-nodes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) dom property to get hold of the text node coming after the checkbox

Try

```
function clickCheckbox() {
    alert("Selected -- " + $.trim($(this.nextSibling).text()));
}
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#idCheckbox").click(clickCheckbox);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8h6KU/)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [label](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) for the text and use the for attribute.